# Finding missing dates from a collection

Tags: c#, recursion

I've dates array with values below:
"07/07/2011", "08/05/2011", "09/07/2011", "12/07/2011"

Using this as input in my C# program, I need to build a new collection which will have missing dates..ie. 10/07/2011, 11/07/2011.

Is recursion the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Recursion is not often the answer. But as for the question, 1) Should "08/05/2011" be "08/07/2011"? 2) Is the implied pattern the actual pattern, as in you have monthly intervals for your supplied and missing dates?

Comment: For ideas, see these questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=missing+dates+%5Bc%23%5D

Comment: Are you storing these as strings or datetimes?

Comment: It's a great toy problem. Will probably keep this as an interview question.

Comment: No, it is actually 08/05/2011 and not 08/07/2011. I can store these dates either as string or as datetime.

Comment: Is this MDY or DMY.  Either way I'm a bit confused by the 08/05/2011 entry.

Comment: How does "08/05/2011" make sense in that scheme? You're following some other incrementing rule besides the 7th of each month. What is it?

Comment: well, I dont have control over these dates as they are coming from a different system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all. This should be a straightforward process. You have a starting date, you have an interval... You start walking the array and if the next value does not match your previous value plus the interval you insert a new value into the new array. If it does match, you copy that value.

If you need more data (metadata) about each entry then create a class that holds the date and whatever metadata you find useful (e.g. a bool like this_value_was_inserted_artificially)

Using recursion would unnecessarily complicate things.

Answer (score 4):

No recursion needed. This can probably be optimized, but should do the job:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> FindMissingDates(IEnumerable<DateTime> input)
{
    // get the range of dates to check
    DateTime from = input.Min();
    DateTime to = input.Max();

    // how many days?
    int numberOfDays = to.Subtract(from).Days;

    // create an IEnumerable<DateTime> for all dates in the range
    IEnumerable<DateTime> allDates = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays)
        .Select(n => from.AddDays(n));

    // return all dates, except those found in the input
    return allDates.Except(input);
}
```

Comment: Looks like the OP is looking for an interval of *months*, though.

Comment: @Dan Tao: that will depend on whether you are american or not.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot I'm in America where we write our dates ass-backwards ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can pull this off very nicely with Linq:

```
var dates=new[]{
    DateTime.Parse("07/07/2011"),
    DateTime.Parse("08/07/2011"),
    DateTime.Parse("09/07/2011"),
    DateTime.Parse("12/07/2011")};

var days=(dates.Max()-dates.Min()).Days;

var otherDays=
    Enumerable
        .Range(0,days)
        .Select(d=>dates.Min().AddDays(d))
        .Except(dates);
```